# jQuery scroll to element not working

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm putting together a calendar/events page using two columns. I've managed to make some of the scrolling work (auto scroll to current event/month; scroll to event details by clicking on event summary in the calendar), but for some reason i just can't seem to get the up/down scrolling to work for either column. I'm setting a ".current" class on the previous/next selector, which works.. but the scrolling is a no go. Not getting any errors either.

The line where it must be going wrong is

```
container.animate({
    scrollTop: $('.current').offset().top -
                  container.offset().top +
                  container.scrollTop()
}, 500)
```

I'm fairly certain i'm just overlooking something simple, but if anyone has a suggestion as to what, I'd very much appreciate it!

**Update:**
I've managed to find the issue with regards to the up/down scrolling not working. I was referencing the wrong selector.

However, I now encounter a new problem. On first click (up or down), nothing scrolls although the class "current" is properly set. On second click (same direction) things scroll, though the list will never reach the first/last item. On clicking in the opposite direction, the list continues to scroll in the -previous- direction once, then continues to scroll in the correct direction.

I hope my description isn't causing confusion :) Try the fiddle and you'll probably see what I mean.

Updated code can be found over at http://jsfiddle.net/4E4V8/3/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put alerts within the `if` and `else if` of `alert(scrollTo.offset().top + ', ' + container.offset().top + ', ' + container.scrollTop());` you'll see that even though the object doesn't move on the first click, `scrollTo.offset().top` changes from the first to the second click. I have no idea why, but it doesn't. After I compared the difference inbetween the first and the second click and looked at the CSS for the object, I found that the difference in between the first and second click was the object's height + it's margin-bottom (your only vertical margin).

As a result, I simply changed the line

```
container.animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
}, 300);
```

to

```
container.animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo.height() + parseInt(scrollTo.css('margin-bottom')) + scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
}, 300);
```

[Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4E4V8/5/).

Using alerts, especially with variable values, is incredibly useful for debugging

Comment: Nice.. Your change works perfectly! Still having a minor issue where in the page i'm implementing this script on, it doesn't quite scroll to the exact top of each box, but i'll try to figure that one out somehow. And I agree, alerts are the way to go.

Comment: It could be due to some other CSS property on the boxes affecting their vertical positioning like `margin-top` or a similar property

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect but here is a starting point: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/U8c22/)

I've changed the html, so it would make more sense to me:

```
  <div id="events-container">
        <div id="events-detail">
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="nav"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="events-overview">
            <div class="container"></div>                                    
            <div class="nav"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The .js is still not 100% right, but the main idea is :

```
function navUp(e) {
        // get .container div
        var container = $(this.parentElement.previousElementSibling);
        // find .current event div
        var current = container.children(".current");
        // get the up span
        var button = $(e.target);
        // does .current event div has a next event div ? 
        if(current[0].nextElementSibling){
           // add .current to next event div
           var next = $(current[0].nextElementSibling).addClass("current");
           // remove .current class from original event div
           container.children("div").not(next).removeClass("current");
           // animate
           container.animate({
            scrollTop: current[0].nextElementSibling.offsetTop - current.offset().top
           }, 100);
        }
    };
```